# InvalidCastException on select XP machines

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, .net-4.0

I am having a problem with a tool that I wrote in VB.NET running on certain XP machines. The tool runs fine and as expected on Windows 7 and XP machines that have .NET 4.0.30319.1022.

I've noticed the XP machines that I am having trouble on are those that did not have .NET 4 even on it, so I went and installed .NET 4 which puts on version .NET 4.0.30319.1.

Here is the error:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/SUHhy8q.png]

Here is the code at line 86 (86 is the For Each):

```
'_BIOSVer
Dim bios_query As String = "SELECT * FROM " & "Win32_BIOS"
Dim bios_searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(bios_query)
For Each info As ManagementObject In bios_searcher.Get()
    _BIOSVer = info.Properties("BIOSVersion").Value.ToString()
Next info
```

I am running Windows Updates for .NET 4 Framework to see if that will fix the issue, but I was wondering if you guys might have a sense of what is happening, or if my code is just wrong.

Updates just finished, restarted. It is running off of .NET 4.0.30319.1022 but still throws that error. Must be my code then.

Comment: Perhaps not every object returned in the collection from `ManagementObjectSearcher` is a `ManagementObject` ?

Comment: The stack trace doesn't help, you'd have to capture it on the first chance exception.  Flaky WMI provider, surely.  Change your query to SELECT BIOSVersion instead of SELECT * to minimize the risk.

Answer (score 1):

BIOS Version returns a string array (for more information check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Try reading the data like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim BIOSSearcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT BIOSVersion FROM Win32_BIOS")
    Dim BIOSVersionInfo() As String = BIOSSearcher.Get(0).Properties("BIOSVersion").Value
    Dim BIOSVersion As String = ""

    If Not BIOSVersionInfo Is Nothing Then
        BIOSVersion = String.Join(vbCrLf, BIOSVersionInfo)
    End If

    MsgBox(BIOSVersion)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems, but mainly `BIOSVersion` is a string array.  Rather than poking into that, you can just get the `Name` which returns the version info (so does `Caption` and `Description`).  Since you are after one thing, you dont need a loop, but I left it in as a template:

```
Dim myver As String = ""
Using searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("Select Name From Win32_Bios")
    For Each mo As ManagementObject In searcher .Get

        ' EXAMPLE
         'DebugProperties(mo)

        ' no real need to Loop - just for illustration
        For Each pd As System.Management.PropertyData In mo.Properties

            ' if you do SELECT * and want to find something,
            ' compare Pd.Name to the target property 

            ' some things can be nothing.  Such as when a property does not
            ' exist on older systems, so always test:
            If pd.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                myver = pd.Value.ToString
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Using

Return myver
```

This is a helpful WMI debug tool to display all the property names and values (the code above has the call to this commented out):

```
Private Shared Sub DebugProperties(mo As Management.ManagementObject)

    For Each pd As PropertyData In mo.Properties
        If pd.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", pd.Name,
                              If(pd.Value IsNot Nothing,
                                 pd.Value.ToString,
                                 "Nothing"))
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Curious, how would I go about not using a for loop?

Comment: Note that I used "select Name" not "select *" so there is only one thing in the collection, so there is only one thing.  You way was assigning *other* prop values like "Manufacturer" over the top of Manufacturer. It would have left the last thing there, which happens to usually be "Version".  You can also compare `pd.Name` to the name of the property you are looking for.